# normalizing ggplot2 densities with facet_wrap in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am making a series of density plots with `geom_density` from a dataframe, and showing it by condition using `facet_wrap`, as in:

```
ggplot(iris) + geom_density(aes(x=Sepal.Width, colour=Species, y=..count../sum(..count..))) + facet_wrap(~Species)
```

When I do this, the y-axis scale seems to not represent percent of each `Species` in a panel, but rather the percent of all the total datapoints across all species.

My question is: How can I make it so the `..count..` variable in `geom_density` refers to the count of items in each `Species` set of each panel, so that the panel for `virginica` has a y-axis corresponding to "Fraction of `virginica` data points"?

Also, is there a way to get ggplot2 to output the values it uses for `..count..` and `sum(..count..)` so that I can verify what numbers it is using?

**edit**: I misunderstood `geom_density` it looks like even for a single `Species`, `..count../sum(..count..)` is not a percentage:

```
ggplot(iris[iris$Species == 'virginica',]) + geom_density(aes(x=Sepal.Width, colour=Species, y=..count../sum(..count..))) + facet_wrap(~Species)
```

so my revised question: how can I get the density plot to be the fraction of data in each bin? Do I have to use `stat_density` for this or `geom_histogram`? I just want the y-axis to be percentage / fraction of data points

Comment: one option is to simply transform the data.frame

Comment: @Ricardo: how? Make a new dataframe?

Comment: exactly,  melt + dcast  from reshape2

Comment: @Ricardo: not sure how an example would help. can I still plot `iris` main df and just feed `geom_density` a transformed `data=` argument?

Comment: I'm not convinced that ggplot2 is displaying the wrong y values for you. You seem to be calculating a density estimate on `..count.. / sum(..count..)` which won't result in the "percent of each species".

Comment: @joran: you're right in the sense that `ggplot(iris[iris$Species == 'virginica',]) + geom_density(aes(x=Sepal.Width, colour=Species, y=..count../sum(..count..))) + facet_wrap(~Species)` also doesn't give percentage. so I'll edit my question to clarify, thanks

Comment: @user248237dfsf, I meant calculate the values you want plotted first, then use that as the data argument for ggplot

Comment: Maybe you're confused about what a density is? The area under it should sum to one, but that doesn't mean each point will represent a "proportion of total values". In fact, density functions often stretch above 1.

Comment: @joran: I understand densities, I just want a histogram fundamentally, so that each y-value is the fraction of data in that bin. so I guess geom_density is the wrong primitive here. Can you offer an alternative?

Comment: @baptise: yes! thanks! if you put it as an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, what you are asking ggplot2 to do is define separate y's for each facet, which it syntactically cannot do AFAIK.

So, in response to your mentioning in the comment thread that you "just want a histogram fundamentally", I would suggest instead using `geom_histogram` or, if you're partial to lines instead of bars, `geom_freqpoly`:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, ..count..)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(colour=Species, fill=Species), binwidth=.2) +
  geom_freqpoly(colour="black", binwidth=.2) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]

**Note: geom_freqpoly works just as well in place of geom_histogram in my above example. I just added both in one plot for sake of efficiency.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Alright, I managed to work out a quick-and-dirty way of getting what you want. It requires that you install and load `plyr`. Apologies in advance; this is likely not the most efficient way to do this in terms of RAM usage, but it works.

First, let's get iris out in the open (I use RStudio so I'm used to seeing all my objects in a window):

```
d <- iris
```

Now, we can use `ddply` to count the number of individuals belonging to each unique measurement of what will become your x-axis (here I used Sepal.Length instead of Sepal.Width, to give myself a bit more range, simply for seeing a bigger difference between groups when plotted).

```
new <- ddply(d, c("Species", "Sepal.Length"), summarize, count=length(Sepal.Length))
```

Note that `ddply` automatically sorts the output data.frame according to the quoted variables.

Then we can divvy up the data.frame into each of its unique conditions--in the case of iris, each of the three species (I'm sure there's a much smoother way to go about this, and if you're working with really large amounts of data it's not advisable to keep creating subsets of the same data.frame because you could max out your RAM)...

```
set <- new[which(new$Species%in%"setosa"),]
ver <- new[which(new$Species%in%"versicolor"),]
vgn <- new[which(new$Species%in%"virginica"),]
```

... and use `ddply` again to calculate proportions of individuals falling under each measurement, but *separately* for each species.

```
prop <- rbind(ddply(set, c("Species"), summarize, prop=set$count/sum(set$count)),
              ddply(ver, c("Species"), summarize, prop=ver$count/sum(ver$count)),
              ddply(vgn, c("Species"), summarize, prop=vgn$count/sum(vgn$count)))
```

Then we just put everything we need into one dataset and remove all the junk from our workspace.

```
new$prop <- prop$prop
rm(list=ls()[which(!ls()%in%c("new", "d"))])
```

And we can make our figure with facet-specific proportions on the y. Note that I'm now using `geom_line` since `ddply` has automatically ordered your data.frame.

```
ggplot(new, aes(Sepal.Length, prop)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour=new$Species)) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image: facet_wrap with facet-specific proportions]

```
# let's check our work. each should equal 50
sum(new$count[which(new$Species%in%"setosa")]) 
sum(new$count[which(new$Species%in%"versicolor")]) 
sum(new$count[which(new$Species%in%"versicolor")])

#... and each of these should equal 1
sum(new$prop[which(new$Species%in%"setosa")]) 
sum(new$prop[which(new$Species%in%"versicolor")]) 
sum(new$prop[which(new$Species%in%"versicolor")])
```

Comment: I think you are right and it's freqpoly... I thought ..density.. does it but that's still a density and not a fraction

Comment: Yes, though freqpoly still only gives you a count. Like I said though, if you want a fraction, what you're essentially asking for is to calculate your fractional y-values with a different denominator for each facet, which I don't think is possible in ggplot2.

Comment: ah I see. That is what I want though, a different denominator for each facet. Do i have to manually calculate that?  how can that be done?

Comment: I think so, but that'll likely require some creative use of the package(s) plyr or reshape2. You'll need to fiddle with your data.frame until you have a column of bins and another column of proportions of members of each condition belonging to each bin. Then you can use x=bin, y=proportions, and group=condition (=="Species" in the iris data). But I'm running low on time so I can't test this at the moment...

Comment: you totally got what I am looking for... whenever you get chance if you have an example with iris data i'd love to see it and learn from it thanks

Comment: Alright, I've updated my answer to hopefully solve what you were looking for.

Comment: thanks! final q on this: what controls the bin width when you count things up here to get the proportions?

Comment: In this example, because I am simply recording the *unique* values of my dependent variable, binwidth is a direct function of the measurement's precision. If you want wider bins with this method, you'll have to specify a range and count the number of observations falling within this range manually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using table() and barplot() you might be able to get what you need. I'm still not sure if this is what you are after...

```
barplot(table(iris[iris$Species == 'virginica',1]))
```

With ggplot2

```
tb <- table(iris[iris$Species == 'virginica',1])
tb <- as.data.frame(tb)
ggplot(tb, aes(x=Var1, y=Freq)) + geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the argument `scales='free_y'` to `facet_wrap()` should do the trick.